# C# error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Socket' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Tags: c#

I write a client-server program in C# to send words or libraries to client and to get their answer such as if they want to add new words or libraries to a dictionary or not. My problem is the libraries System.Net.Sockets and System.Net are not recognized or properly connected. Would you Plz help me with what is going wrong here?

### here is my code:

```
using System;    
using System.Net;    
using System.Net.Sockets;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading;    

namespace Dictionary.Net.SocketWrappers    
{    
    public class ServerSocket
    {
        private Func<string, string> _getMessage;
        private Socket _socket;
        public readonly int backlog;
        public readonly Encoding encoding;
        public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, Func<string, string> getMessage, Encoding encoding)
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            var iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            _socket.Bind(iPEndPoint);
            this.backlog = backlog;
            this._getMessage = getMessage;
            this.encoding = encoding;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _socket.Listen(backlog);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                return;
            }
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = _socket.Accept();
                    if (client != null)
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ClientThread, client);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ClientThread(object newClientObject)
        {
            var newClient = newClientObject as Socket;
            var clientSocket = new ClientSocket(newClient, encoding);
            bool IsListening = true;
            while (IsListening)
            {
                try
                {
                    var receivedData = clientSocket.Receive();
                    var dataToSend = _getMessage(receivedData);
                    clientSocket.Send(dataToSend);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    IsListening = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of all references which I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pq3t.jpg)

Comment: Did you reference the package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Sockets/

Comment: added a screenshot of all references which I have in VS 2017

Comment: So you didn't add a reference to the package?

Comment: You're showing us the references for the `Server` project whilst the errors are being raised in the `Client` project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick Hofman already answered, you're missing a reference to `System.Net.Sockets`.

You can use the Visual Studio Package Manager to get it from NuGet.

The window can be accessed over the menu with `VIEW > Other Windows > Package Manager Console`

[image: Location of the Packet Manager]

In the console, you have to simple write your requested package.

So in your case write `Install-Package System.Net.Sockets`.

[image: the console window]